# How do i restrict Text Prompt validator delegate to be called every time whenever there is a prompt?

Tags: python-3.x, botframework

I have a waterfall Dialog with 6 steps , each of them have a Text prompt to gather user input.

**Text prompt**

```
self.add_dialog(TextPrompt(TextPrompt.__name__,ChoiceDialog.text_prompt_validator))
self.add_dialog(
        WaterfallDialog(
            WaterfallDialog.__name__,
            [
                self.project_step,     #TextPrompt
                self.description_step, #TextPrompt
                self.name_step,        #TextPrompt
                self.date_step,
                self.confirm_step,
                self.final_step,
            ],
        )
    )
```

When the user enters a value the Validator is invoked and we have an opportunity to check/change the outcome.

But, i don't want the validator to be called every time there is a TextPrompt. Or Maybe call the validator delegate with different validations for each step.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just construct multiple text prompts.

```
self.add_dialog(TextPrompt("prompt:project", ChoiceDialog.project_validator))
self.add_dialog(TextPrompt("prompt:description", ChoiceDialog.description_validator))
self.add_dialog(TextPrompt("prompt:name", ChoiceDialog.name_validator))
```